# How to check if a GET call is not made in $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angularjs-ngmock

$httpBackend offers methods for check if an HTTP call is made:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/auth.py');
```

I'm testing a service that has an internal cache and I would like to check if it works correctly. The idea is to check if the GET call is NOT made after a second request.

I'm using Karma and Jasmine.

Comment: expectGet has to be setup for each GET request. If an unwanted call is made it will fail, as remote invocation is not allowed during unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
it('should be cache', function() {

 myCacheStuff();
 $httpBackend.flush();
 $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
})
```